# Как обратиться к элементу Matrix библиотеки Jama (нужно построить график)

Tags: java, библиотеки, график, матрицы

Произвела сингулярное разложение при помощи библиотеки `Jama` следующим методом:

```
public static void SVD (Matrix A) { 
   System.out.println("\n \nСингулярное разложение производится в виде: \nA = U S V^T");
   System.out.println("\n, где А - исходная матрица ");
   SingularValueDecomposition s = A.svd();
   System.out.print("U (Слова) = ");
   Matrix U = s.getU();
   U.print(9, 6);
   System.out.print("Sigma (Сингулярные значения) = ");
   Matrix S = s.getS();
   S.print(9, 6);
   System.out.print("V (Документы) = ");
   Matrix V = s.getV();
   V.print(9, 6);
   System.out.println("Ранг матрицы = " + s.rank());
   System.out.println("Число обусловленности (точность решения задачи) = " + s.cond());
   System.out.println("2-норма = " + s.norm2());
   // print out singular values
   System.out.print("Сингулярные значения = ");
   Matrix svalues = new Matrix(s.getSingularValues(), 1);
   svalues.print(9, 6);
}
```

Для параметра метода из двумерного массива сделала нужный тип данных

```
Matrix A = Matrix.constructWithCopy(IndMatrix);
SVD(A);
```

Проблема в том, что теперь мне нужно построить график по точкам - элементам полученных матриц. Как к ним обратиться, если традиционное для массивов `A[i][j]` не работает?
Какие библиотеки вообще посоветуете для построения графика?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете получить двумерный массив из нужного Вам объекта типа `Matrix`.

```
Matrix A = Matrix.constructWithCopy(IndMatrix);
SVD(A);
double[][] values = A.getArray();
```

[Ссылка на документацию](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/)

Comment: А список сразу можно получить?

Comment: @ВикторияПушкина насколько я знаю, сразу нельзя